# Select rows that has common relationship

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:
Book

```
| id | book_title |
|----|------------|
| 1  | a          |
| 2  | b          |
| 3  | c          |
| 4  | d          |
```

Teacher:

```
| id | teacher_name |
|----|--------------|
| 1  | a            |
| 2  | b            |
| 3  | c            |
| 4  | d            |
```

Education stage:

```
| id | education_stage_name |
|----|----------------------|
| 1  | a                    |
| 2  | b                    |
| 3  | c                    |
| 4  | d                    |
```

The relationship between book and education stage:

```
| book_id | education_stage_id |
|---------|--------------------|
| 1       | 1                  |
| 1       | 2                  |
| 2       | 3                  |
| 3       | 4                  |
```

And the relationship between book and teacher:

```
| book_id | teacher_id |
|---------|------------|
| 1       | 1          |
| 1       | 4          |
| 2       | 3          |
| 3       | 4          |
```

Now I want to select books, which has the same education stages as a teacher with `id=1`
So the result table should look like this:

```
| book_id | title |
|---------|-------|
| 1       | a     |
```

Because only the education stage with `id=1` is assigned to the book and the teacher with `id=1` at the same time.

Here is the [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vezbQPqU2iASTctA2xPiEs/0), but I don't know even how to start with this query.
Is there anyone that has some ideas on how to write this query?
Is it possible to write it with DQL language?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't take anything complex, if all records will always exist, you can `inner join` on all tables:

```
select 
    Book.id as book_id,
    Book.book_title,
    Teacher.id as teacher_id,
    Teacher.teacher_name
from Book
inner join book_education_stage bes on bes.book_id = Book.id
inner join Education_Stage es on es.id = bes.education_stage_id
inner join teacher_education_stage tes on tes.book_id = Book.id
inner join Teacher on tes.teacher_id = Teacher.id
```

Result:

| book_id | book_title | teacher_id | teacher_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 | a |
| 1 | a | 1 | a |
| 1 | a | 4 | d |
| 1 | a | 4 | d |
| 2 | b | 3 | c |
| 3 | c | 4 | d |

Here is the [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vezbQPqU2iASTctA2xPiEs/2) if you're interested.